# Is this French text (year 1558) describing a spirit level more than 100 years before this tool was invented?

Tags: histoire, ancien-français

It is accepted that the [spirit level](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spirit_level) ([niveau à bulle d'air](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais-anglais/niveau/54313#660503)) was invented by [Melchisedech Thevenot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Melchis%C3%A9dech_Th%C3%A9venot) (1620 - 1692) some time before February 2, 1661. However, some people interpret a 1558 text, referring to an insect, as mentioning a *spirit level* more than one hundred years before it was created by Thevenot...

A 1558 French text describing a spirit level more than 100 years before it was invented?!

[image]

<sup>[*Histoire entière des poissons*](http://docnum.u-strasbg.fr/cdm/compoundobject/collection/coll13/id/27045/show/26409), [Guillaume Rondelet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guillaume_Rondelet), 1558</sup>

[image]
<sup>[*Plumb bob level*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plumb_bob) [[fil à plomb](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/anglais-francais/plummet/602675), [plomb](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/anglais-francais/plumb/602663), [niveau à]](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/anglais-francais/level/592020#639558)</sup>

Do you, as a native French speaker, consider that the text talks about a spirit level or does the paragraph refer to a plumb bob level, a tool invented in antiquity?

Comment: It says the insect has the shape of a T or a level ("niveau"), with three feet on each side (or three feet overall). Does not look like a Spirit Level ("Niveau à bulle" in french). There is no mention of a bubble ("bulle") anywhere.

Comment: Parce que je ne suis pas sûr que ce soit *la* réponse, ça se discute justement.

Answer (score 4):

The text describes the freshwater insect that is called by the author "niveau d'eau douce" and is drawn just below the title.
Looking like a hammer shark, its T shape evokes a "niveau". It also has three legs on each side.

In this text, the only reference to an inclinometer is the word "niveau". It is used to give a name to the insect because their shapes are similar.

As indicated by @SimonMourier, there is no indication of the level technology (spirit or plumb bob level).

```
 The insect is a dragonfly larvae (larve de libellule)
```

[image]

Comment: It became clear that the 1558 text refers to a T shape level which was called "hammer fish" in Italy, that time. This is a plumb bob level. A spirit level is not like a T and has no common features with the insect described in the book.